# LastIndexOf bug?

Tags: c#, .net

I have following simple code for searching ',' in specified position:

```
string str = "LogFail (verificationStep, \"Die zu vergleichenden Listen haben nicht die gleiche Größe/Länge! \" + \"Erwartete Länge: \" + expValue.Count + \" Aktuelle Länge: \" + actValue.Count, expectedValueAnalysis, actualValueAnalysis, \"\", String.Join (\":\", actualValue.ToArray ()))";
int index = str.LastIndexOf(',', 223, 262 - 223);
Console.WriteLine(index);
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(221,15));
```

The output is senseless:

```
221
, String.Join (
```

Length of the string is 265. Maximum index reached by LastIndexOf() should be 262. How it is possible that it returned 221 when starting index is 223???

Thank you in advance.

**SOLVED**

I have understood documentation wrong. The direction of search is opposite than expected.

Comment: When encountering an unexpected behavior. Reading the documentation is probably the first thing to do. Investigating the issue to better understand the behavior is a good second step.

Comment: There's a handy phrase you might find some good reads from - `select isn't broken` - you should almost always assume the problem is in the code you wrote rather than being a bug in a broadly distributed library or OS function.

Comment: It is probably easier to use `String.Split` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs:
[`public int LastIndexOf (char value, int startIndex, int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> "The search proceeds from `startIndex` toward the beginning of this instance."

The first comma *before* index 223 occurs at index 221.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_System_Int32_) says:

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified string within this instance. The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds **backward** toward the beginning of the string for a specified number of character positions.

Since the search runs backward, the comma will found at the position before.